# How to I dispatch a state value to an const variable in Redux-toolkit?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, redux-toolkit

I am trying get an error to show in my component which is being dispatched from my actions and assigned to my **errorAlert** constent, however it always comes back as null even when there is content in my state as per `console.log`. I have shared the console log results below.

Is there an issue when assigning a redux state variable to a const?

**slice.js**

```
const auth = createSlice({
    name: "auth",
    initialState: verifiedResult: {},
    reducers: {
        verifySuccess(state, { payload }) {
            state.verifiedResult = payload;
            state.isLoading = false;
            state.error = null;
        }
    }
```

**action.js**

```
...
if (result.state === "pending") {
    await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 10000));
       } else if (result.state === "failed") {
            dispatch(verifySuccess(result));
    break;
```

**component.js**

```
....
const errorAlert =
        auth.verifiedResult.cel_number === false
            ? "The number associated with your account is not a valid."
            : auth.verifiedResult.prepaid_number === false
            ? "Mobile number is not Prepaid or is not active."
            : auth.verifiedResult.has_recharged === false
            ? "Mobile number must be recharged in the past 30 days"
            : null;
return (
<>
{errorAlert && <div>{errorAlert}</div>}
</>
)}
```

**console.log**

```
::auth.verifiedResult::
{
state: "failed"
cel_number: 'XXX XXX XXX'
prepaid_number: false
recharged: false
}

:::errorAlert::: null
```

[image]

Comment: I suggest you create a minimal reproducible example that shows the problem (on some website like codepen, codesandbox, etc.). For instance do you use `cel_number` or `number`? `prepaid_number` or `prepaid`? `has_recharged` or `recharged`? It's hard to know what is a typo and what is the cause of the bug.

Comment: Okay I will recreate it on codepen and share soonest. 

Answer (score 1):

It shows `Mobile number is not Prepaid or is not active.` in my case. Make sure your `auth.verifiedResult` is correctly written(you don't use comma after every object property).

```js
const auth = {};

auth.verifiedResult = {
  state: 'failed',
  cel_number: 'XXX XXX XXX',
  prepaid_number: false,
  recharged: false,
};

const errorAlert =
  auth.verifiedResult.cel_number === false
    ? 'The number associated with your account is not a valid.'
    : auth.verifiedResult.prepaid_number === false
    ? 'Mobile number is not Prepaid or is not active.'
    : auth.verifiedResult.has_recharged === false
    ? 'Mobile number must be recharged in the past 30 days'
    : null;

console.log(errorAlert); // Mobile number is not Prepaid or is not active.
```

Comment: ``auth.verifiedResult`` content comes from an api and I am just dispatching to the ``errorAlert`` and console logging it.

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean

`if (result.state === "pending")`?

Comment: You are correct. Its a typo whilst summarizing the code for stack overflow...